# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timescale.fields'

Tags: python, django, timescaledb, modulenotfounderror

I have downloaded django-timescaledb but when i run server, the following error is displayed in terminal:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'timescale.fields'`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import uuid
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import F
from django.utils.timezone import now
from timescale.fields import TimescaleDateTimeField



User = get_user_model()

class TimescaleModel(models.Model):
  """
  A helper class for using Timescale within Django, has the TimescaleManager and
  TimescaleDateTimeField already present. This is an abstract class it should
  be inheritted by another class for use.
  """
  time = TimescaleDateTimeField(interval="1 day")

  class Meta:
      abstract = True
```

[Terminal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/006nj.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `"ModuleNotFoundError"` in Python despite installing the module, there are a few possibilities.

- Verify that you are importing the correct module name in your code. Check the module name's spelling and capitalization.
- Check the installation: Import the module in a Python shell to see if it is correctly installed.
- Check the Python version: Make sure the module you installed is compatible with the Python version you're using. Some modules may only work with specific Python versions.
- If you can import the module in the shell but not in your code, there could be a problem with the environment or the module's location.

If you are unfamiliar with `virtual environments`, try using them to track your packages more easily. A virtual environment is a self-contained Python environment that allows you to install Python packages and dependencies specific to your project without interfering with other projects or the system's overall Python installation.

This means you can set up a virtual environment for each project and install only the packages needed for that project, without having to worry about conflicts or compatibility issues with other packages or projects on your system.